# How to make this conditional be true in C++

Tags: c

Somebody know how to make `char str[20]="reviver",palind=1` be true `printf("%s eh palindromo.\n",str)`?

My code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[20]="reviver",palind=1;
    int tam = strlen(str);
    int i=0; char cont = tam;
    for(; i <= cont; i++,cont--)
    {
        if(str[i]!=str[cont])
        {
            palind=0;
            break;
        }
        cont--;
    }
    if(palind)
        printf("%s eh palindromo.\n",str);
    else
        printf("%s nao eh palindromo.\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You decrease `cont` twice every iteration of the loop, is that intended?

Comment: no, what I want is to check if the word is written backwards it is a palindrome (to be itself again)

Comment: Then think about what you're doing with `cont--` *twice*. Try to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their variables, to see what really happens in your code.

Comment: Thank you i fix it this and other lines, now it works

`int i=0, cont = tam-1;
for(; i <= cont; i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope if you do two corrections in line numbers 7 and 15 as below, you may get expected result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[20]="reviver",palind=1;
    int tam = strlen(str);
    int i=0; char cont = tam-1;
    for(; i <= cont; i++,cont--)
    {
        if(str[i]!=str[cont])
        {
            palind=0;
            break;
        }
        /*cont--;*/
    }
    if(palind)
        printf("%s eh palindromo.\n",str);
    else
        printf("%s nao eh palindromo.\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare `cont` as `char`? This will limit the string length to `127`.

Comment: I already thanks in other comment, but I want to thanks again for everyone that help me. I fix it and change other lines, now it works `int i=0, cont = tam-1; for(; i <= cont; i++)`